# HTML/CSS image navigation menu

Tags: html, image, css, url

So, I've been programming for a few years now and have been dreading making a website because HTML and CSS are not programming languages, and for some reason they confuse me to no end!

Here is a link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLbm8emv/) where I have the HTML and CSS code that I though would show an image and, on hover, would display a different image. I remember doing this in the introductory course to C.S. years ago.

After looking at multiple examples of how to do this simply, copying code and implementing my images where the example code had their own images, and still coming up with a blank screen, I'm coming to you guys to show me the idiotic thing that I am miss.

Sorry in advance for how elementary this is!

HTML:

```
<body> 
    <a href="#" class="about" title="Learn more about me!"></a> 
    <a href="#" class="work" title="Look at what I made!"></a>
    <a href="#" class="contact" title="Talk to me!"></a> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.about {
    width:400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/images/about.png);
}
.about:hover {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/images/aboutHover.png);
}

.work {
    width:400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/images/work.png);
}
.work:hover {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/images/workHover.png);
}

.contact {
    width:400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/images/contact.png);
}
.contact:hover {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/images/contactHover.png);
}
```

My dir tree:

```
[SITE]-
    |—index.html
    |
    |—[ css ]
    |   |—base.css
    |   
    |—[ images ]
    |   |—about.png
    |   |—aboutHover.png
    |   |—contact.png
    |   |—contactHover.png
    |   |—name.png
    |   |—nameHover.png
    |   |—work.png
    |   |—workHover.png
    |
[SITE]-
```

Comment: Are you sure your image paths are correct? http://jsfiddle.net/fLbm8emv/1/

Comment: I was thinking the same http://jsfiddle.net/fLbm8emv/2/

Comment: @brettwbryon you should include text inside the anchor elements for accessibility, ie screen readers. Simply push the text way off of the screen so it cannot be seen: `text-indent: -99999em`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/images` should be `images` if the [relative path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_path) of your index file is on the same level.

```
background-image: url(images/workHover.png);
```

---

`dir/index.html` = `../images` to go up one directory and down into images

`dir/dir/index.html` = `../../images` to go up two directoris and down into images

Comment: After looking at my dir tree, I realized I needed to go up a dir to get to my images folder. I usually have my HTML and CSS files in the same dir, but I'm working with multiple CSS files for the first time, and that was my issue. I need to add the ../ before my image. I did, and it works perfectly. Thanks for helping me realize my ridiculous mistake!

Comment: Im happy to have helped, hey a few dots are easy to overlook sometimes.

Comment: Using separate images like you have for hover and non-hover states will cause a flicker the first time someone hovers the link. Include both states in a single image and use `background-position` to prevent the flicker.

Comment: @hungerstar How would I implement that code? I haven't worked with HTML and CSS very much, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out css sprites, http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ on top of what @hungerstar recommends =)

Comment: I'm also finding it difficult to size different images of similar sizes to one set size without large gaps in height. Any insight to that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body>

        <a href="#" class="about" >Learn more about me!</a> 
        <a href="#" class="work" >Look at what I made!</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact">Talk to me!</a> 
    </body>
```

Comment: I don't want that text to actually show in the html. It is only for hovering over the link.